# Moving 3d character in godot using python handtracking program

Tags: python, godot

I made this python program that tracks my finger coordinates and sends them to my gdscript in order to move the character but i cant get the character to move and i dont really know why. I will give the code here and please let me know whats wrong, i dont get any erros or nothing so thats why im asking here.

here is the handtracking program code

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import socket

mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mphands = mp.solutions.hands

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
hand = mphands.Hands()

# Socket setup
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"   # IP address of the Godot machine
UDP_PORT = 5005        # Port number for communication
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
    data, image = cap.read()
    image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.flip(image, 1), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = hand.process(image)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
        for hand_landmarks in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            # Extract the coordinates of the tip of the pointer finger landmark (index 8)
            cx, cy, cz = int(hand_landmarks.landmark[8].x * image.shape[1]), int(
                hand_landmarks.landmark[8].y * image.shape[0]), int(hand_landmarks.landmark[8].z * image.shape[1])
            # Send the fingertip coordinates to the client (GDScript)
            message = f"{cx},{cz}".encode()
            sock.sendto(message, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

            # Draw a circle at the fingertip
            cv2.circle(image, (cx, cy), 5, (0, 255, 0), -1)

    cv2.imshow('Handtracker', image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and here is my gdscript

```
extends RigidBody

var x_coordinate = 0
var z_coordinate = 0

#var move_speed = 1000  # Adjust the movement speed as needed
var max_speed = 200    # Maximum speed limit

var server := UDPServer.new()
var peers = []


func _ready():
    server.listen(5005)

func _process(delta):
    
    move_character()
    
    server.poll() # Important!
    if server.is_connection_available():
        var peer : PacketPeerUDP = server.take_connection()
        var pkt = peer.get_packet()
        var data = pkt.get_string_from_utf8() # Get received data and remove leading/trailing whitespaces
        var coordinates = data.split(",") # Split the data by comma to get individual coordinates
        if coordinates.size() >= 2: # Ensure we have at least two coordinates (x and z)
            var x = coordinates[0].to_float() # Convert the first coordinate to float
            var z = coordinates[1].to_float() # Convert the second coordinate to float
            print("Received coordinates - X:", x, " Z:", z) # Print the received coordinates
        else:
            print("Invalid data format received:", data) # Print error message if data format is invalid
            
        
        
func move_character():
    # Check if the coordinates are received
    if x_coordinate != 0 and z_coordinate != 0:
        # Move left or right based on x-coordinate
        if x_coordinate < 300:
            # Move left
            apply_central_impulse(Vector3(-100, 0, 0))
        else:
            # Move right
            apply_central_impulse(Vector3(100, 0, 0))
        
        # Move forward or backward based on z-coordinate
        if z_coordinate < 0:
            # Move forward
            apply_central_impulse(Vector3(0, 0, -1))
        else:
            # Move backward
            apply_central_impulse(Vector3(0, 0, 100))
        
        # Limit maximum speed
        if linear_velocity.length() > max_speed:
            linear_velocity = linear_velocity.normalized() * max_speed

func update_coordinates(new_x, new_z):
    x_coordinate = new_x
    z_coordinate = new_z
```

thanks for taking ur time helping a fellow godot noob <3